# detecting movement on touch began phase in Corona SDk

Tags: events, sdk, lua, touch, coronasdk

In my application I want an object to slide and jump on *touch began* event in Corona. Although I am successful in implementing both slide and jump on *touch ended* event, but making event phase at *began* I can't do slide.

I use the following code for sliding and jumping:

```
function touched( event )
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    if(event.x - event.xStart > 70) then
      sliding = true;
      offGround = true; 
    else
      boy:applyLinearImpulse(0, -0.44, boy.x, boy.y)
      offGround = true;
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this. I use moved phase and mark a boolean active on move phase and call a timer function at began. Here is my code.

```
function Action()
    if(Slide == true)then
        Slide = false;
        sliding = true;
    else
        if(jump == true)then
            meter = -0.54
            boy:applyLinearImpulse(0, meter, boy.x, boy.y)
        end
    end
end

function touched( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    print(phase)

    if(phase == "moved")then
        Slide = true;
        jump = false;
        print("Boy is Sliding")
    end
    if(phase == "began")then
        if  Slide == false then
            print("Boy is not Sliding")
            jump = true
        end

        timerNew = timer.performWithDelay(100 , Action , 1)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want to do, event began by definition is when it began, thus event.x and event.xStart is the same always, it is impossible to detect how much you moved a finger on event began, because it just began, thus there are no past to compare with.